# file_get_contents and cURL both not working on hosted website

Tags: php

`file_get_contents(urlencode($url))` as well as `cURL`  not working on hosted website. However both work fine on localhost.
on server I get below message

> **cURL Error: Failed to connect to xx.xxx.xx.x port 5000: Connection refused**

In the url I am also passing parameter. My `$url` is as below

```
http://xx.xxx.xx.x:5000/request_data?device=' . $dev_id
```

Tried `file_get_contents($url)`, `file_get_contents(urlencode($url))` and also `cURL`

```
$url = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.x:5000/request_data?device='.$dev_id ;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$curVal = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curVal === FALSE) {
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($curl);
 }
echo $curVal;
curl_close($curl);

or 
$url = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.x:5000/request_data?device=' . $dev_id ;
$curVal = file_get_contents(urlencode($url));
```

on localhost it works correctly and returns as below

> {"Bool5": 0, "Bool4": 0, "Bool7": 0, "TotalQtyReg": 0, "Bool1": 0, "Bool3": 0, "Bool2": 0, "DId": "device0219", "TimeStamp": "2019-06-03 08:37:54", "Bool8": 0, "Status": "Success", "CRCMatched": 1, "Bool6": 0, "TotalQtyBool": 8}

Thanks , but I am new , so can you please tell how to run `curl-v` on command line on web server I couldn't find any option on cpanel

I also tried to create `custom php.ini` and set `allow_url_fopen = ON`
but still no success.

Thanks @Álvaro González , But I have one doubt , if the firewall is culprit, I think then it should not run from java script also. However it is working fine if raise same request from java script. From java script I used xmlHTTPRequest.

Yes @Álvaro González, if I tried to raise the request from browser(java script  xmlHTTPRequest) its working fine. I am not using node. so do you suggest me to use node ?

Today I also check IP blocker entry from my cpanel, but there no ip is blocked. :( :( :(

One more thing I tried: I put below lines in my php script

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

and then in response I got some information as below

### Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 447
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2019 10:13:20 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
```

### Request Headers

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: <myhost>.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
```

Please does this give any clue for the solution?

Oh okay so I guess some configuration or setting must be done at server side.

thanks @Dom, I am not sure about whether its Apache or Nginx. It's a Google drive, OS is Ubuntu and the data coming from hardware devices is stored on that. For that they used flask Python. and  its handled by third party. 
The problem is stand still and am trying to convince to open the port 80/8080 instead of 5000.

Comment: try `curl -v http://xx.xxx.xx.x:5000/request_data?device=id` in command line

Comment: "Connection refused" suggest they have a firewall that blocks outgoing connections.

Comment: That's right, it shouldn't work either from JavaScript when running it on the same machine. But, is that your case? There're server-side runtimes like Node but you mention `XMLHttpRequest`, which typically runs in browsers :-?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use Node. I'm just stating that if a firewall is blocking outgoing connections in the server then being able to run code successfully in an entirely different computer does not add further information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're running Nginx or Apache in your server, but if you are, switching from http to https should fix the connection refused error, as it did for me a number of times, here is the link to a guide, that will tell you exactly what to do:

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx